# Position 4 div horizontally in react. The first at the beginning and the 2,3,4 near the end

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to achieve something like that

[image]

where each "COL" is a div . I would like to be able also to easily edit in the future the distance especially between COL2,3,4 .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play around with this

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.col {
  background-color: teal;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.col:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="col">Col1</div>
  <div class="col">Col2</div>
  <div class="col">Col3</div>
  <div class="col">Col4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use margin property on first child and gap on flex container.

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="list__item">COL1</div>
  <div class="list__item">COL2</div>
  <div class="list__item">COL3</div>
  <div class="list__item">COL4</div>
</div>
```

```
.list{
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: greenyellow;
}
.list__item{
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}
.list__item:first-child{
  margin: 0 auto 0 0;  
}
```